# Picking balls from boxes, a logical approach?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> You have a box with ten purple balls, five red balls, five blue balls,
> three yellow balls. You pick out four balls at random. What is the
> probability of all four balls being the same color?

I've interpreted this question in two ways and got two answers based on how its read. I've made a quick program for both and over one million trials, I've come upon the following:

> If you take a ball and put it back (ie. ball pool is the same always), it's a 4% chance
>
> If you take a ball and hold onto it (ie. ball pool decrements by one four times), it's a 2% chance
>
> If you take four balls at once (ie. ball pool decrements by four once), I think it's still a 2% chance

Here are the two programs:

[image: Algorithm 1]
[image: Algorithm 2]

But what is a more declarative way of solving this to ensure my answers are correct? Over an infinite amount of trials I should reach some accuracy, but is there a formulaic approach?

Comment: There are ${23 \choose 4}$ ways to pick $4$ balls out. You can pick out $4$ purple balls in ${10 \choose 4}$ ways, $4$ red balls in ${5 \choose 4}$ ways and $4$ blue balls in ${5 \choose 4}$ ways. So $\dfrac{{10 \choose 4}+2{5 \choose 4}}{{23 \choose 4}}$ altogether. This is approximately a $2\%$ chance, as your program indicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split it into disjoint events, and then add up their probabilities:

---

The probability of picking $4$ purple balls is $\dfrac{\binom{\color\purple{10}}{4}}{\binom{\color\purple{10}+\color\red{5}+\color\blue{5}+\color\green{3}}{4}}=\dfrac{210}{8855}$

---

The probability of picking $4$ red balls is $\dfrac{\binom{\color\red{5}}{4}}{\binom{\color\purple{10}+\color\red{5}+\color\blue{5}+\color\green{3}}{4}}=\dfrac{5}{8855}$

---

The probability of picking $4$ blue balls is $\dfrac{\binom{\color\blue{5}}{4}}{\binom{\color\purple{10}+\color\red{5}+\color\blue{5}+\color\green{3}}{4}}=\dfrac{5}{8855}$

---

The probability of picking $4$ yellow balls is $\dfrac{\binom{\color\green{3}}{4}}{\binom{\color\purple{10}+\color\red{5}+\color\blue{5}+\color\green{3}}{4}}=\dfrac{0}{8855}$

---

Hence the overall probability is $\dfrac{210}{8855}+\dfrac{5}{8855}+\dfrac{5}{8855}+\dfrac{0}{8855}=\dfrac{220}{8855}$

Comment: yellow is hard to see